# how to remove duplicate values from specific columns in a data frame?

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, duplicates

I want to remove duplicate text within certain column values of the data frame.

like this..

[image]

what should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base R`, we can split the 'originaltext' column by `,` followed by zero or more spaces (`\\s*`), then loop over the `list` with `sapply`, get the `unique` values and `paste` them by `collapse`ing without space

```
df1$result <- sapply(strsplit(df1$originaltext, ",\\s*"),
       function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse=""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(original_text, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(result = paste0(unique(original_text), collapse = ''), 
            original_text = toString(original_text)) %>%
  select(-row)
```